# How can I use a variable in BATCH's type command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arduino, windows-console

I wrote a little batch script to parse my html file into a cpp-Header file so I can compile it to an ESP8266 (PROGMEM). The Script is really simple:

```
@echo off
set /P filename=Enter File name (w/o .html extension): 
if exist "..\website\%filename%.html" (
    echo|set /p dummyvar=%filename%>beforetemp.txt
    type before.txt beforetemp.txt before2.txt "..\website\%filename%.html" after.txt > "..\server\%filename%html.h"
) else (
    echo FILE at website\%filename%.html DOES NOT EXISTS!
    pause
)
exit 0
```

Everything worked just fine before I added the part where I can input the name of the file I want to copy.

The all done file should look like this:

```
#include <arduino.h>

const char indexhtml[] PROGMEM = R"====(
<html>
...
</html>
)====";
```

But as I run the script it inserts a space character at the end of *beforetemp.txt* and therefore screws up the variable name in my indexhtml.h file. The stuff with *before.txt beforetemp.txt before2.txt* becomes

```
#include <arduino.h>

const char index html[] PROGMEM = R"====(
```

instead of

```
#include <arduino.h>

const char indexhtml[] PROGMEM = R"====(
```

**The Question is: How can I print the content of %filename% between before.txt and before2.txt into my new file?**

---

Here are the used files:

before.txt

```
#include <arduino.h>

const char
```

before2.txt

```
html[] PROGMEM = R"====(
```

after.txt

```
)====";
```

Comment: To make that clear: the problem is definetly in line 4 of the script, the type command itself works flawlessly since the space-char is already present in the beforetemp.txt text file.

Comment: Why do you use `type` and not `copy` to create one file from several other files? Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `copy /?` and read the output help. It is possible to run `copy` with option `/B` and several input files with `+` between them and one output file name to copy the contents of the input files in specified order into the specified output file. `type` outputs also the files names on running it with multiple file names and I doubt that this results ever in a valid header file.

Comment: Replace `echo|set /P dummyvar=%filename%` by `< nul set /P ="%filename%"`…

Comment: @aschipfl works absolutely as itended, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated the problem was in the line where I echoed %filename% into my temp-file.
I changed the line

```
echo|set /p dummyvar=%filename%>beforetemp.txt
```

to

```
< nul set /P ="%filename%">beforetemp.txt
```

and everything works fine now.

---

The complete batch-file now looks like this:

```
@echo off
set /P filename=Enter File name (w/o .html extension): 
if exist "..\website\%filename%.html" (
    < nul set /P ="%filename%">beforetemp.txt
    type before.txt beforetemp.txt before2.txt "..\website\%filename%.html" after.txt > "..\server\%filename%html.h"
) else (
    echo FILE at website\%filename%.html DOES NOT EXISTS!
    pause
)
exit 0
```

Comment: Actually, user Compo already incorporated that in his answer, so this answer is kind of a duplicate; (in addition, Compo even improved the method of concatenating files by using `copy` instead of `type`…)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest with the following content:

`before.txt`

```batch-file
#include <arduino.h>

const char
```

`before2.txt`

```batch-file
html[] PROGMEM = R"====(
```

`after.txt`

```batch-file
)====";
```

that you use the following batch file, using `Copy` instead of `Type`:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set /P "filename=Enter HTML file name without extension: "
If Not Exist "..\website\%filename%.html" (
    Echo website\%filename%.html does not exist.
    %__AppDir__%\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak > NUL
    Exit /B 2
)
< NUL Set /P "=%filename%" > "beforetemp.txt"
Copy "before.txt" + "beforetemp.txt" + "before2.txt" + "..\website\%filename%.html" + "after.txt" "..\server\%filename%html.h" /B
Exit /B %ErrorLevel%
```

*Please note that this does not currently delete your, probably now not required, `beforetemp.txt`, so you may wish to incorporate a method of doing that before exiting.*

Comment: Quoting paths is a good practice. `"%__AppDir__%\timeout.exe"`

Comment: I have never found that quoting that specific implementation necessary, @lit. Whether that's because systems which use it, no longer use a \system32 directory in a location with spaces or problematic characters, may be the reason. If you could show me that there's sufficient reason to believe that this special dynamic variable, is likely to resolve to a path which would require doublequoting outside of what cmd.exe does, I'd be happy to concede.

Comment: We have no control over what the value of `__appdir__` might be. Only Microsoft does. And Microsoft could put anything it wants there. It is a good habit for defensive programming.

Comment: They could also remove the necessity to need doublequotes or auto quote if there's problematic characters noted, @lit. Why worry about defending possible but very unlikely, future changes to the way cmd.exe works, especially when its becoming deprecated due to powershell.exe?

Comment: Well, @lit and @Compo, why not relying on the `PATH` (and also `PATHEXT`) variable(s), like so many programs and scripts do on Windows? would it not be easier and more legible when you just state `timeout.exe` (or even `timeout`)? If you really want to make your script independent from the variable(s) you could check or even set it (them) at the beginning; when using `setlocal`/`endlocal` in your script the original state eventually becomes restored…

Comment: @aschipfl, the way I see it, and believe me on this site I do more often than I would have ever expected, the `%PATH%`, variable is often modified and often incorrectly. Also a user can modify the content of `%SystemRoot%`, `%WinDir%` etc, delibertately or otherwise, but cannot do that with `%__AppDir__%`. The `%PATHEXT%` is less critical, but I see no reason not to use an extension, when I know it? _I see no real reason to ask cmd.exe to look for something, when I already know the information it's looking for!_

Comment: In addition to @Compo's comments, I have seen tools install their own executable files that have the same name as Windows\System32 files. Often, it is some level of UNIX/Linux layer such as MKS Toolkit. If it gets in the PATH before the standard commands, `find` becomes a different animal.